# How to add elements to an ArrayList from another classB when I am in a method of classA?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to access the existing ArrayList from class MonthlyMgr from another class DailyMgr where I pass the value from DailyMgr into the ArrayList from MonthlyMgr. However I keep getting error saying that my ArrayList is empty even though I had some values in it already. May I ask how am I able to call the ArrayList from MonthlyMgr together with the values inside? Thank You!

Class DailyMgr

```
IRevenue monthly = new MonthlyMgr();
monthly.addRevenue(month, monthRevenue);
```

Class MonthlyMgr

```
public ArrayList<Monthly> monthlyList = new ArrayList<Monthly>(12);

public void addRevenue(int month, double earning) {
        monthlyList.add(month-1, new Monthly(month, earning));
}
```

Comment: You might be accessing two different objects of `MonthlyMgr` class. In your `DailyMgr` you have created an object of `MonthlyMgr`, `monthly` and adding to that object. In order to see those added elements you need to access the `monthly` object itself.

Comment: @GauthamM May I ask how can I call the Monthly class's ArrayList directly as I've tried many ways and it either give me error or returns me a newly created ArrayList... 
What I wanted was that in DailyMgr class I check if it's the last day of the month and if it is, I will collate everything and add it to MonthlyMgr's ArrayList. Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing rest of the code, it is hard to suggest a solution. The thing is that since your array list is not `static`, it belongs to the "object" and not the "class". So if you update an arraylist within an object of `Monthly`, then all other objects of `Monthly` **will not** have those values. Only the specific object in which you added those values will contain them. I would suggest you try out some examples to understand the concept of classes and objects in java.

Comment: Thank you! After understanding the concept of static, I found out how and managed to solved my issue! Thank you so much @GauthamM!